# "NullreferenceException: Object not Set to instance of an object" with Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages.FormsSignInPage

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I'm trying to make a sign in page for Sharepoint 2010 using Forms Based Authentication.
I followed a tutorial and ended up with my project showing the above error (object not set to instance of an object).

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages.FormsSignInPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +119
   NDELogin.Layouts.NDELogin.Login.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +65
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2427

Would someone take a look at the Code/Aspx and tell me if you see anything wrong.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages;

namespace NDELogin.Layouts.NDELoginc
{
public partial class Login : FormsSignInPage
  {
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
  }
}


    <%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
    <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
    <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

    <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" %>

    <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" 
        Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" 
        Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
    <%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" 
        Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>

    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" 
        Inherits=" NDELogin.Layouts.NDELogin.Login, NDELogin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5da7e3f4f8be720c" MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/NDELogin/PublicMaster.master" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentLogin"
        runat="server">
         <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server"
            EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode" ID="ClaimsFormsPageTitle"
            Visible="false" />
             <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server"
            EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode" ID="ClaimsFormsPageTitleInTitleArea"
            Visible="false" />

        <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server"
            EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode" ID="ClaimsFormsPageMessage"
            Visible="false" />
        <asp:Login ID="signInControl" FailureText="<%$Resources:wss,login_pageFailureText%>"
            runat="server" Width="100%" DisplayRememberMe="false" />
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: I just answered my own question... set  MembershipProvider="FBAMembershipProvider" on the login control

Comment: You should move your comment into an answer to your own question and then accept it when the 2 day wait period is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered my own question... set MembershipProvider="FBAMembershipProvider" on the login control

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you did? Your answer doesn't make much sense to me.